# Insert line break in editor

Tags: java, eclipse, editor

I'm trying to add a line break with the Find function in eclipse - What I want to do is put a line after each method in all my classes [I liked them all close together but now its hard to read through]. so I figure theres 2 ways to do this.

**1.** Find all with "public" and change to "\npublic", \n being the new line in a string to give you the idea of what I mean.

**2.** A convenient eclipse shortcut that separates all the methods in a class with an empty line.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? I'll be happy as long as it works and I don't have to go through every method in the project myself and push enter .-.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #2, you can set the Eclipse auto-formatter to do so for you.

Look under the Preferences panel; in the left side (tree), select Java Code Style (click the arrow to expand the section), then Formatter. You can then decide to use a single formatting style for all of your projects, or check the box to apply a special set of formatting rules to just the current project. Some of the options include where to locate whitespace and newlines.

You can also use the “Save Actions” panel to re-apply the same formatting rules every time you save your files. Personally, I use (and team members as well) this method, to ensure that the formatting for the files is always consistent. By mechanically reformatting in this way, changes to the file will always show up “properly” in Subversion/Git — I don't accidentally have whitespace-only changes being introduced into files showing up as “false positive” changes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check box 'Regular Expressions' and use '\R' for Linebreak in the 'Replace with' box in eclipse
2. configure the auto-formatter its a bit of work for the first time but its worth, when ever you get ugly formatted code you can fix this in seconds ..